# How can I get the text use xpath from the text?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I want get `111111111` use `xpath` from the `text`, I do it this way below, but I cannot get it.

```
import lxml
text = """<p class="tel">
<span class="dsTitle">tel:</span>
111111111
</p>
"""
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring(text, parser=lxml.etree.HTMLParser())
tel = doc.xpath('//p/text')
print(tel)
```

The output is `[]`.I think I can get `111111111`.
But Why? What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget the brackets.

```
doc.xpath('//p/text()')
```

will work.

Comment: How does this answer differ to mine?

Answer (score 0):

**Use [xpath node test](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#node-tests) `text()`:**

It selects all children of type text-node of your context-node `p`.

Append the filter `/text()[normalize-space()]` to remove leading and trailing white-space nodes, like new lines and whitespaces.

**Complete:**

```
tel = doc.xpath('//p/text()[normalize-space()]')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can used xpath as follow:

```
//span[contains(text(),'tel:')]/following-sibling::text()[1]
```